# "protection" and "secure" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the use of the [protection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protection) and [secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secure) tags, are they useful?

If yes, I think they deserve a Wiki description because I their usage do not seem obvious to me and they seem used for very various purposes.

Answer (score 7):

My impression after a non-exhaustive review:

- [secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secure) is totally meaningless on this site and can and should be nuked.
- [protection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protection) is sometimes meaningful but is not a good tag name. The tag should be removed from the site, but on about half questions that have it, it should be replaced by some other tag such as [defense](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defense), [access-control](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/access-control), [integrity](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integrity), etc.

Comment: Agreed - I have just removed the [tag:secure] tag from those posts, and will ask for it to be blacklisted.

Comment: Oh - I see it already was: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/1291/485

Comment: Agreed. Both [tag:secure] and [tag:protection] should be removed. Gilles' suggestions seem to work well.